# Issue with bundle object

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i have problem with bundle object. When i pass data (onCLick button) from activity to fragment i get values of bundle object and after i pass values to adapter... after that i have problem: bundle object get again values from activity(but now values is null) and pass null values to adapter...i don't know why after the first time bundle get again value from activity...I hope that you can help me

I show toy my code

ACTIVITY:

```
     Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putIntegerArrayList("oki", hm);
            bundle.putIntegerArrayList("okiquantitapizze", hm_quantitàpizze);

            System.out.println("PERO:" + bundle);
/*
            MyListFragment2 myFragment = new MyListFragment2();
            myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.pero, myFragment);
            transaction.commit();*/

            MyListFragment myFragment = new MyListFragment();
            myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.a, myFragment);
            transaction.commit();
```

FRAGMENT:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        System.out.println("BUNDLES1 prima:" + bundle);


        bundle = getArguments();

        System.out.println("BUNDLES1 dopo:" + bundle);
        if (bundle != null) {


            strtext2 = bundle.getIntegerArrayList("oki");
            quantitàpizze2=bundle.getIntegerArrayList("okiquantitapizze");
            System.out.println("CAZZ2:" + strtext2);

            System.out.println("PRESO2:" + quantitàpizze2);




        }



}
```

Comment: Can you paste your whole Activity? And also what are you doing when the bundle gets passed again e.g. are you rotating your screen, coming from another app, etc?

Comment: no, when i click button before pass data in right way and after repass data.....so the fragment is created two time....

Comment: any news on this?

Comment: no..i have same the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Add a static `newInstance()` method to your fragment.

```
public static MyListFragment newInstance(ArrayList<Integer> list1,ArrayList<Integer> list2) {
MyListFragment myListFragment = new MyListFragment();

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putIntegerArrayList("oki", list1);
bundle.putIntegerArrayList("okiquantitapizze", list2);
myListFragment.setArguments(bundle);

return myListFragment;
}
```

And instantiate fragment like this:

```
        MyListFragment myFragment = MyListFragment.newInstance(list1,list2);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.a, myFragment);
        transaction.commit();
```

Comment: i tried but i have the same problem..i don't know why

Comment: i put fragment into layout of activity that contain fragment

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is not to recreate the fragment, there is not need. Add a tag to your fragment when you add it.

```
transaction.replace(R.id.a, myFragment, "MyListFragment");
```

In you fragment create a method like this:

```
public void updateValues(ArrayList<Integer> list1, ArrayList<Integer> list2){
    //do your stuff and update the UI 
}
```

Then in onClick() just find the fragment and call the method.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        MyListFragment fragment = (MyListFragment) manager.findFragmentByTag("MyListFragment");
        if (fragment != null && fragment.isVisible()) {
            fragment.updateValues(list1, list2);
        } else {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putIntegerArrayList("oki", list1);
            bundle.putIntegerArrayList("okiquantitapizze", list2);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            manager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.a, fragment, "MyListFragment")
                    .commit();
        }
    }
```